# Parse only a specific part of image with Tesseract

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to use Tesseract OCR on Android to read the state of a gas meter when you take a picture of it: [image: picture]

This is the output when I parse this image:

```
vb"
22% BK-G4T ||||||||I||||I|||ii\|||\
’ 64 2007
22?: 06.0"! 'm'lm Mm. 23212274 ,
v 2,0 dm’ 1
pmn 0_5 bar tm ~25°C v‘40"(1 I
1amp é 0_o1m’ sb15°cl :Sp 20°c l
'I ELSTEQ~I¢¢>>InstrogwnSs HB Z _ 18 _ 1013 . ‘
a, 069373593435- 3 I
i'23212214 Y _ w w V'
g
```

The idea is to extract the first 5 digits of the state of the gas meter ( 06937 on this image ).

My question is, is there a way to train Tesseract to only parse this part of the image? Absolute coordinates are not an option since every picture would be different. I am guessing the best logic would be something like: parse only white numbers on black background.

Answer (score 2):

By changing the `page segmentation mode (psm)`, `tesseract 4.00.00 alpha` is able to read the meter line characters correctly as `06937598-m3` apart from other characters.

The command used is:

```
tesseract meter.jpg output --psm 11 -l eng
```

`--psm 11` means to recognize `"Sparse text. Find as much text as possible in no particular order"`.

Here is the `output` file with showing all the ASCII control characters.

[image]

If `--psm 11` works on other meter images, then you could just need to search `-m3` at the end of the line to extract the who meter line characters. With that, you can get the first 5 digits right away.

Hope this help.

Comment: I am not sure if tesseract 4 has support for android. I am using tess-two in my project. The problem with this approach is that m3 is sometimes not visible. (eg: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYoZm.jpg) I am going to try and isolate the part of the picture I need with OpenCV.